# DOMPDF generation error

Tags: php, centos, debian, genpdf

I have a big problem at my work. We had to make a page who displays a exercise for the users. But that page need also to be available as pdf. To do this we used DOMPDF. This worked perfectly on your development server but when we moved it to the production server dompdf generates pdf with errors.

When i open the pdf i get the error from Adobe Reader: 110.

The first server (development) was Debian. The production server runs CentOS 5.

DOMPDF used PDFLib or CPDF, but both generate the same error.

Does anybody know what kind of differents on the server i need to be aware of ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague found the problem. It had something to do with localization.
We have changed %f in sprintf to %F for localization independent floating point notation in PHP. A very strange problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with DOMPDF 0.5.1. Your fix is the correct resolution and is included as part of the upcoming 0.6.0 release. You can find a beta release of the next version on the developer site: http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/